# private constructor in java enumerator

Tags: java, oop, enums

What are the differences between these two below definitions of enum in Java , and what is the advantage of the first one over the second one ?

```
public enum Suit {//first definition
   CLUBS (1), SPADES (2), HEARTS (3), DIAMONDS (4);
   int value;
   private Suit(int v) { value = v; }
};

public enum Suit {//second definition
   CLUBS, SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS;
};
```

Comment: What makes you think that there is an advantage? It all depends on what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: why the downvotes? I find the question to be meaningful

Answer (score 2):

In this example there is no difference other than obvious 'int value'.

In general the enum in Java 5+ is a class with some restrictions.
You can't create an instance of enum by yourself with 'new' as you do it with usual classes.

On the other hand enums can have data fields just like regular class and even methods.

What if your enum would represent, say, planets, and each instance of enum would contain some really useful data like radius of the planet?
In this case you would code something like this:

```
public enum Planet {

    EARTH(6000), VENUS(5000);
    int radius;
    private Planet(int radius) {this.radius = radius;}

     // now define a getter:

     public int getRadius() {

         return radius;
     } 
}
```

Note the getter here. It will allow to get the access to this kind of data right from the enum instance.

For example:

```
public void somewhereInYourCode(...) {

   .....
    Planet p = getPlanet(); // get the planet from your system 

    int radius = p.getRadius();
   ....
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a field, you use the first one and if you don't need a field you would use the second.

Its about choosing the right code for the requirements you have.

Answer (score 1):

Not much difference. First one is just clearer to read + it has builtin function for setting the value. It's just the way you prefer writing your code. 
That would be like comparing something like

```
if (outOfBounds){
doSomething();}
```

and `if(outOfBounds == true){
doSomething();}`

Answer (score 1):

If you use  `Suite` with a private constructor you can do `Suite.CLUBS.value`, if you use the standard `enum` you have to use `Suite.CLUBS.ordinal()`.

Using a private constructor for an `enum` becomes more interesting if you add other properties to your `Suite`.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using the an int to refer to the value of the enum, it might be better to use the first variant instead of relying on the index number of the enum value.

This way it is first of all more clear which int value belongs to which enum value, and it also does not break if you ever change the order.